# How to hide or remove (not disable) the Show Desktop button at the end of the taskbar in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

**Edit:** This question has already been answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/564489/168632) for Windows 7, the answer remains the same, however people looking specifically for how to fix it for windows 10 may never see it so I am leaving this one here as well.

---

I konw you can disable the peek functionality from the settings, but I was wondering if you could remove it completely. In previous versions of windows if I'm not mistaken, when you disabled peek it would remove that area altogether, and it would be nice to be able hide it in Windows 10 as well. I'm talking about this area right here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer myself, there's an app called 7+ Taskbar Tweaker that can be used for this. I'll leave this question open because I'd prefer to know the exact Registry setting for this and not rely on a 3rd party app for it.

[image]

Credit: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-show-desktop-button-windows-10/